# Hiding a sibling listbox when a textblock is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone

I was wonder if any one knows how to change the visibility of a listbox within a DataTemplate when a sibling is clicked. The DataTemplate is being used on a listbox. The following is an example of the xaml I'm using:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="Template1">

                <StackPanel Margin="110,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Name="ShowHide" Text="Hide" Tap="ShowHide_Tap" />
                    <ListBox Name="Listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding SecondList}" Visibility="Visible" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Template2}"/>
                </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
```

The following is my attempt but I can't use the FindName

```
 private void ShowHide_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {


        var item = sender as TextBlock;
        ListBox Listbox = null;
        if (item != null)
        {

            ContentPresenter templateParent = GetFrameworkElementByName<ContentPresenter>(item);

            DataTemplate dataTemplate = templateParent.ContentTemplate;
            if (dataTemplate != null && templateParent != null)
            {
               Listbox = templateParent.FindName("Listbox1") as ListBox;
           }
            if (Listbox != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("ERROR!"));
            }
            else
                Listbox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }


}

        private static T GetFrameworkElementByName<T>(FrameworkElement referenceElement) where T : FrameworkElement
        {
            FrameworkElement child = null;
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(referenceElement); i++)
            {
                child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(referenceElement, i) as FrameworkElement;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(child);
                if (child != null && child.GetType() == typeof(T))
                { break; }
                else if (child != null)
                {
                    child = GetFrameworkElementByName<T>(child);
                    if (child != null && child.GetType() == typeof(T))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return child as T;
        }
```

If any one has any insights they would be much appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It so happens that the Blend SDK provides functionality for this -- you can even use XAML only, no code behind.  Just use an [`EventTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.eventtrigger%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) (on the "Tap" event) along with a [`ChangePropertyAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.changepropertyaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx).  Here's how it looks:

```
<TextBlock Name="ShowHide" Text="Hide" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetName="Listbox1" 
                PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBlock>
<ListBox Name="Listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding SecondList}" Visibility="Visible" />
```

Note that this requires you to add references to the following Extensions:

- `System.Windows.Interactivity`
- `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions`

Reference them in XAML with the namespaces:

- `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`
- `xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"`

Comment: Hope you don't take offense at me throwing in my own two cents here....just because something can be done in XAML doesn't necessarily mean that doing so is a good idea. The minute you switch functionality to XAML you immediately lose the ability to debug the behavior and you also lose the ability to unit test. Yes, it does mean you can use Blend, but the people typically using Blend are not the people you want having any control over view logic whatsoever. Create design time data, expose that to the designers using Blend and keep logic control in the sole domain of the programmers.

Comment: @McGarnagle Thanks, that solved my issues and did exactly what I asked, thank you very much.

Comment: @MarkFeldman You raise interesting points and I would like to be able to create the same effects using my code however, I have trouble getting access the sibling elements when using a DataTemplate, I have found a number of examples doing it for a specific Listbox but I cant seem to get them to work for my DataTemplate, if you have any references I would be glad to get them.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Generally speaking this is not the way to use WPF, especially if you're using DataTemplates. The purpose of the view in WPF is to display the view model and fire off user events, nothing more. By changing the Data Template at run-time you're effectively storing the state of the view inside the view itself. This runs totally against the grain of how WPF was designed to be used.

To do this properly your view model (i.e. the class with the `SecondList` property) should have an extra property called something like `ListBoxVisibility` and you would bind your listbox's `Visibility` member to that. An even cleaner method is to use a bool and then use a converter in the view to convert it from type bool to type Visibility. Either way the view model should also have a property of type ICommand (e.g. `OnButtonPressedCommand`) that the button invokes when the user presses it. The handler for OnButtonPressedCommand, which should also be in the view model, then sets `ListBoxVisible` or whatever to the value you want which then propagates through to the list box. Doing things this way keeps good separation of concerns and means the view model can be created and its visibility-changing behavior unit tested independently without having to create the view itself.

Comment: I have previously implemented this using a Convertor to convert a Boolean to Visibility, however, my issue with this method is that it requires the information on the ListboxItem to be re downloaded as each ListboxItem contains an image which gets it's source from a URI. I probably could cache each image but I don't want to fill up the isolated storage with images.

I will look into using ObservableCollections as I think that this will allow the ListboxItem contents to change without the need to reassign the Listbox ItemSource, is this correct?